# Form in react gives back: "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

i writed this component in reacrt which makes a new post, it is a really simple component with a form that should sumbmit the text when the button is clicked, but when i click the "submit" button it gives back this error:
"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

What am i doing wrong ?

```
import classes from "./NewPost.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function NewPost(props) {
  const [enteredBody, setEnteredBody] = useState("");
  const [enteredAuthor, setEnteredAuthor] = useState("");

  function bodyChangeHandler(event) {
    setEnteredBody(event.target.value);
  }

  function authorChangeHandler(event) {
    setEnteredAuthor(event.target.value);
  }

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const postData = {
      body: enteredBody,
      author: enteredAuthor,
    };
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="body">Text</label>
        <textarea id="body" required rows={3} onChange={bodyChangeHandler} />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" required onChange={authorChangeHandler} />
      </p>

      <p className={classes.actions}>
        <button type="button" onCancel={props.modalHandler}>
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}

export default NewPost;
```

Comment: More info: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected

Comment: I did all of that already that is the problem